# Firestore Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firestore

O mesmo código se faço ele dentro de uma página html, ele funciona:

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script>

      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XYZ",
        authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "XYZ",
        storageBucket: "XYZ.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XYZ",
        appId: "XYZ"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      let db =null;
      if(!firebase.apps.length){
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        db = firebase.firestore();
      }

      const id = new Date().getTime();
      const userid = new Date().getTime();
      let docRef = db.collection("alarms").doc("teste"+id);

      docRef.set({ userid: userid  }, { merge: true }).then((id)=>{
        console.log("ID:",id);
      }).catch(
        (err)=>{
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
```

Acima, substitui as informações sigilosas por XYZ para colocar aqui no site, se precisarem coloquem suas proprias configurações.

O exemplo acima peguei do google e funciona perfeitamente.

Já, dentro do servidor node, no backend, usando as seguintes dependências:

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "appengine-typescript",
  "description": "An example TypeScript app running on Google App Engine.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r source-map-support/register index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async_hooks": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "3.3.0",
    "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",
    "js-sha1": "^0.6.0",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.1",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },      
}
```

E com o seguinte código:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as firebase from "firebase-admin";

 if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XYZ",
        authDomain: "XYZ.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "XYZ",
        storageBucket: "XYZ.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XYZ",
        appId: "XYZ"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
}

const db = firebase.firestore();

const cmpID = "cmpid:" + new Date().getTime();
const userid = "userid" + new Date().getTime();


let docRef = db.collection("alarms").doc(cmpID);

docRef.set({ userid  }, { merge: true }).then((id)=>{
    console.log("ID:",id);
  }).catch(
    (err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

Neste cenário, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at process.nextTick (/mnt/c/Users/gandb/Documents/workspace/vriend/v-alarm/services/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:100:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  code: 7,
  details: 'Missing or insufficient permissions.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
```

As permissões no Firestore estão assim:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow  create,read, write, update, delete: if true;
    }
    }
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado na versão do node JS? Tem que fazer algo a mais para funcionar, faltou importar alguma dependência?

Comment: Pelo caminho, parece que você está usando o WSL. Poderia testar mover a pasta de /mnt/c para sua home do Linux?

Comment: Olá Julio. Eu mudei para a minha home e o erro permanece , só que agora o caminho aponta para a home (/home/gandbanco/temp/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26) , por via das dúvidas fiz até um teste de mudar a permissão do diretório na home para 777 mas parece não ter relação alguma com permissão de diretório, pois o erro não mudou.

Comment: Então deve ser falta de permissões no Firebase mesmo. Confere no Firebase Console se você tem as regras de read e write como true. Olha essa thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied

Comment: Adicionei no post as regras do firebase, não acredito que seja as regras pois mesmo com janela anonima, deslogado do google, quando o código esta no html funciona, mas no nodejs não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o erro, ocorre esta mensagem por diversos motivos diferentes, um deles que não encontrei documentado em lugar algum, mesmo no stacoverflow em inglês, ocorre quando você autentica no google sdk com um usuário que tem permissão para outro projeto, que facilmente ocorre se você gerou as credenciais para um projeto e sem querer usou em outro, no meu caso eu uso docker e criava uma variável de ambiente que apontava pro arquivo json de credenciais do projeto errado, como por exemplo:

```
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS projeto-errado.json
```

No html funciona pois ele não precisa da credencial, mas se for rodar no nodejs o firestore exige a credencial correta para funcionar.